# Deploy code from Github After testing with Travis CI to Azure VM running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, azure, continuous-integration, virtual-machine, travis-ci

I am new to continuous integration and just started using Travis. I want to be able to deploy my code to my Azure VM running ubuntu.
I cannot seem to find any useful resources after googleing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "deploy"

Comment: by deploy I mean when stuff is pushed to Git, the code and all files should be transferred to the server.

Comment: You could use [Travis' integrated deployment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) or just handroll a script in `after_success`